# Downside to setting Redis's set-max-intset-entries too large?

Tags: redis

According to [Redis's memory optimization page](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization) one can set the configurable `set-max-intset-entries` in order to optimize memory for large sets of integers. I did some testing with integers less than 2M, setting `set-max-intset-entries`to 10000. I found that each int averaged about 4 bytes when the set was less than the max, and when longer than the max, each int was about 60 bytes.

However, the memory optimization page also says that there is a CPU/memory trade off when increasing this max. Where does the performance tradeoff come from when increasing this max, and is there any way that I can run tests so I can quantify the tradeoff that I'm making?

Answer (score 1):

The trade off in CPU should be in the time to run a related command such as SADD or SCARD.

A basic process used by Commissar is to pull the commandstats before running a test and after, and determining the differ nice, for example of the SADD command. Do this with a table of settings and look at the results. Of course, you'll want to run the tests repeatedly to get a big sample size.

It should be noted you'll want to do a save and restart in between tests where you change the memory setting as Redis doesn't restructure the data when changing that setting. This is the simplest way to keep the data and use different settings.

Once you hit the threshold you should see the time to run the set of commands increase (or decrease if you're going the other way).